# Compiling Problem with c++ on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04

So I have a debugger problem. So I created a c++ program and I ran it on Ubuntu 16.04. However, when trying to compile by typing in the command line **g++ decrypt.cpp caesor\ cipher.cpp -o decrypt**, it gave me a few errors. this is the first time I've been working on c++ in a long time and was hoping that you guys could spot something I can't. Here is the code and the error below. thank you

=====================================

decrypt.cpp

```
#include"decrypt.h"
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#include<iostream>
Decrypt::Decrypt(string text)
{
    str = text;
    zero_analysis_array();
    //E A R I O are top 5 most commonly used letters in english words
     //initializing keys arrays with thier position in alphabets
    keys[0] = 'E' - 'A';
    keys[1] = 'A' - 'A';
    keys[2] = 'R' - 'A';
    keys[3] = 'I' - 'A';
    keys[4] = 'O' - 'A';
}
void Decrypt::zero_analysis_array()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        freq[i] = 0;
    }

}

void Decrypt::character_count()
{
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
    {
        if (is_alpha(str[i]))
        {
            ch = str[i];
            if (!is_upper(ch))
                ch = to_upper(str[i]);
            int a = ch - 'A';
            if (a > 26 || a < 0)
                cout << "a";
            freq[ch - 'A']++;
        }
    }
}

void Decrypt::print_analysis_array()
{
    char alpha = 'A';
    cout << "\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        cout << char(alpha + i) << " occurs " << freq[i] << " times\n";
    }
    int ind = max_index(), key;
    cout << "Possible keys:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        key = ind - keys[i];
        if (key < 0)
            key = key + 26;
        cout << key << "\n";
    }

}
string Decrypt::decrypt(int key)
{
    string decrypt = str;
    int code, a, b;
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < decrypt.size(); i++)
    {
        if (is_alpha(decrypt[i]))
        {
            ch = 'A';
            if (is_upper(decrypt[i]) == false)
                ch = 'a';
            a = (decrypt[i] - ch);
            b = a + 26 - key;
            code = b % 26;
            decrypt[i] = ch + code;
        }
    }
    return decrypt;

}
void Decrypt::write_to_file(string fname, string text)
{
    fstream file;
    file.open(fname, ios::out);
    file << text;
    file.close();
}
void Decrypt::decryption(string fname)
{
    character_count();
    print_analysis_array();
    string decrypted;
    int key;
    char choice;
    do
    {
        cout << "Select/Enter key(0-26):";
        cin >> key;
        while (key < 0 || key>26)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Key!! Must be between 0-26\nEnter Again:";
            cin >> key;
        }
        decrypted = decrypt(key);
        cout << "\nHere is decrypted text:\n\n" << decrypted;
        cout << "\n\nDo you want to try again with different key? (y/n):";
        cin >> choice;
        while (choice != 'Y' && choice != 'y' && choice != 'n' && choice != 'N')
        {
            cout << "Invalid choice!!.\nEnter (y/n):";
            cin >> choice;
        }

    } while (choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y');
    write_to_file(fname, decrypted);
    cout << "Decrypted text written to file " << fname << "\n";
}
int Decrypt::max_index()
{
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int maxFreq = freq[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    {
        if (maxFreq < freq[i])
        {
            maxIndex = i;
            maxFreq = freq[i];
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
char Decrypt::to_upper(char ch)
{
    if (!is_upper(ch))
        return ch - 32;
    return ch;
}
bool Decrypt::is_alpha(char ch)
{
    return((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'));
}
bool Decrypt::is_upper(char ch)
{
    return (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
}
```

=================================

caesor cipher.cpp

```
#include<fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include"decrypt.h"
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Invalid no of Arguments!!!\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    string text=read_from_file(argv[1]);
    cout << text;
    Decrypt d(text);
    d.decryption(argv[2]);
}

string read_from_file(char* fname)
{
    fstream file;
    string line,text="";
    file.open(fname, ios::in);
    while (getline(file, line))
    {
        text = text + line;
    }
    return text;

}
```

=========================

```
decrypt.cpp: In member function ‘void Decrypt::write_to_file(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string)’:
decrypt.cpp:88:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&, const openmode&)’
     file.open(fname, ios::out);
                              ^
In file included from decrypt.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/fstream:1001:7: note: candidate: void std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; std::ios_base::openmode = std::_Ios_Openmode]
       open(const char* __s,
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/fstream:1001:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’
caesor cipher.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
caesor cipher.cpp:9:15: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
         exit(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the compiler actually tells you what is wrong with your program (and also gives a hint where the error is located).

```
decrypt.cpp:88:30: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&, const openmode&)’
     file.open(fname, ios::out);
                              ^
```

This means your call to `std::fstream::open` is not correct. It expects a C-string and not a C++ `std::string` that you are giving it. 
The easiest fix here would be to change the call to `open` as follows:

```cpp
file.open(fname.c_str(), ios::out);
```

The second error says that it can't find a function named `exit`. This is because the compiler doesn't know this function yet. You need to include the appropriate header (in this case `stdlib.h`) where the function is declared in order for the compiler to know that there is a function called `exit`.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is pretty self-explanatory. It says:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_fstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&, const openmode&)’
```

But it lets you know the closest match would be:

```
note: candidate: void std::basic_fstream<_CharT, _Traits>::open(const char*, std::ios_base::openmode)
```

If you notice, the big difference there is `string` vs. `char *`. So give it the C-string it's looking for:

```
file.open(fname.c_str(), ios::in);
```

However, `open()` should accept `std::string` since C++11. So assuming you're using `g++`, you could also just add

```
-std=c++11
```

when you compile.